# My core autocrlf in git has multiple values, How can I set it to only one?

Tags: git

This is my git config

```
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
http.sslbackend=openssl
http.sslcainfo=C:/Users/XXX/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
core.autocrlf=true
core.fscache=true
core.symlinks=false
credential.helper=manager
user.name=XXX
user.email=XXXX
core.autocrlf=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.autocrlf==
core.autocrlf==
```

As you can see, for some reason I have multiple values for the core.autocrlf and I don´t know how to change it.

Comment: Start with `git config --list --show-origin` and see in what config files it's defined. Then `git config --unset-all core.autocrlf` and then set one `git config core.autocrlf false`

Comment: Thank you so much!